# Creating monthly report of a list

Tags: list, pdf, list-item

I have a list that gets updated every month and currently any item in the list that is over 5 days of the current day gets deleted. However, now I wanted to keep a record of the list items that get deleted every month in either an excel or pdf format.

Could someone please suggest a way I can do this? I have used JavaScript to generate a .iqy file which opens in Excel, but that file is connected to the list in SharePoint and it automatically refreshes whenever the file is open.

I need the report in a format that different users can open without the need to change any settings in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort of game the system.  Instead of giving people stock contribute permissions with delete privs, create a custom permission without it.  Add an additional metatada column to the list that acts as a delete option.  When modified, you replicate any metadata to a separate custom list via workflow then use an impersenation step to actually delete the item.

Then you can run any reports you need to off this archive list.